# Implementing Faded border in .NET or WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net

I want to achieve this in .NET either in WPF or VB.NET

I have a passport size photograph. In that I want to implement a fade effect on image border.
The fade parameter we pass would be the pixel width and we require to fade image border such that fade depth is decided by this parameter.

How can I acheive this?

Note:- I am not using any controls to hold this image. Customer will upload the images in the applications and we will modify the above required and send them through email it is going to be console application. Please dont suggest any WPF or VB Controls to implement this.

Comment: please do not post duplicate questions to get attention, if you want your question to get more attention add a bounty, you have the rep

Answer (score -1):

I would use the System.Drawing namespace and set the alpha value of the pixels. Create a [Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) and then use the [SetPixel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.setpixel.aspx) method to set the alpha value (using GetPixel to get the current color).

If you need some speed improvements, check out this article: [Using the LockBits method to access image data](https://web.archive.org/web/20121203144033/http://www.bobpowell.net/lockingbits.htm).

Comment: The OP is using WPF not Windows Forms

Comment: @ChrisDunaway The OP said WPF **or** VB.NET.

Comment: @webdunia What do you mean how can you use this? Did you look at the documentation I linked to?